# ¿Cómo gestionar los permisos de usuario en Debian?

Tags: debian, permisos, raspberry-pi

Estoy creando un servidor con SSH, pero me ha surgido un problema.

No se como editar los permisos de Linux: tanto los de lectura, escritura, ejecución, como los de el comando `sudo`. He probado editando `sudoers` con `sudo visudo`, pero tampoco cambia nada.

¿Alguien sabe que podría hacer?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: Para cambiar permisos de archivos/directorios, `chmod`. Para cambiar permisos de archivos que no son tuyos, `sudo chmod`.  Claro, necesitas la password de root ...

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo ponerle una contraseña al `root`?

Comment: Quiero que no se pueda usar `sudo` sin la contraseña en NINGUN usuario, ni siquiera en el principal de la raspberry pi (`pi`)

Comment: Google es tú amigo. "Como usar sudo en Linux" -> https://linuxtotal.com.mx/index.php?cont=info_admon_014